# React Native Expo: Update existing app without using OTA

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

I have published the app before using expo cli and let expo to handle all the credentials & apple certificates for me. And now I have changed the app name. How can i update the existing app? Where to get the .p12 file? From my apple developer account, I have download the .cer file but it's type is Apple Push Service which is unable convert to .p12 file. As my understanding, we need a certificate file which type is iPhone Distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the distribution certificate (p12) using this expo command:

```
expo fetch:ios:certs
```

You should **be in the project root** and it will write the certificate on disk and print the password.

Also make sure you are logged in with the right user (use `expo whoami` to check the user and `expo login` to login).